# How to make a Android Gradle build dependent on a simple (non android library, non-java) task that provides a jar file?

Tags: android, gradle

I have a command line program that, depending on a set of source files, generates a jar file that I want to use in my Android gradle build (A). This command line program simply stores a jar file in a directory on the disk.

How can I create a new gradle project (B) that runs my command line program (inside of a gradle multi-project setup) that the Android Gradle project(A) will depend on: in other words, if the sources for B change, it should rebuild!

Note:

Project B is neither a Android library project nor is it a java project. It simply runs a program via command line that happens to store a jar file on the file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by creating your own custom task(s) in project B to execute your program which generates a JAR.  Be sure to declare your inputs/outputs properly so Gradle knows how to handle dependencies for the task:

```
task buildProjB {
    inputs.file file('my_source_file.name')
    ext.dest = new File(buildDir, "libs")
    outputs.dir ext.dest

    doLast {
        //  Run your program and put output in "libs" subdir
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { theTask ->
    if (theTask.name.contains("assemble")) {
        theTask.dependsOn "buildProjB"
    }
}
```

Note that the `buildProjB` task gets "hooked" to any of the `assemble` tasks.  You will likely need to do this or to one of the `build` tasks in order for it to be built properly as part of the normal Android app build.

In your project A `settings.gradle`, make project B part of the build:

```
include ':projectA', ':projectB'
```

In your project A `build.gradle` file, make project B a dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':projectB')
}
```

This is assuming you have project B (module in Android Studio terms) beneath the top level Android Studio project, so at the same level as project A.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One follow up question: How would I specify input and output *directories* instead of *files*? I would like it to rebuild if one of the files inside of the source was changed, or a new one was added.

Comment: The output directories contain other directories. I'd expect gradle to take a hash for the whole destination directory. If the directory changed in any way ( a new file was added, a file is missing etc), I'd like it to count the directory as dirty and not UP-TO-DATE. I can't get this to work.

Comment: You should be able to specify a directory for the outputs, just like shown in my `buildProjB` task above.  That should cause it to look at that directory to determine if it is dirty at all, and if it is it will re-run the task.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `applicationVariants.all` API this will help in running your task dependency for all variants provided by your Android Gradle project

Gradle kts version

```kotlin
android {
    applicationVariants.configureEach {
        assembleProvider.dependsOn(<your task provider>)
        // or in case you have task name
        // assembleProvider.dependsOn(tasks.named(<task name>))
    }
}
```

Groovy version

```
android {
    applicationVariants.configureEach {
        assembleProvider.configure {
            dependsOn <task provider>
            // dependsOn <task name>
        }
    }
}
```